# Rspec - combine expect_any_instance_of and a receive counts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-mocks

I need to verify that any instance of my class receives a certain method, but I don't care if many instances receive it (they're supposed to).

I tried like this:

```
expect_any_instance_of(MyClass).to receive(:my_method).at_least(:once)
```

But apparently, it only allows for a single instance to receive the method multiple times, but not for different instances.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a known issue in rspec-mocks. From the [v3.4 documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) on `Any instance`:

> The rspec-mocks API is designed for individual object instances, but this feature operates on entire classes of objects. As a result there are some semantically confusing edge cases. For example, in `expect_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:name).twice` it isn't clear whether a specific instance is expected to receive name twice, or if two receives total are expected. (It's the former.)

Furthermore

> Using this feature is often a design smell. It may be that your test is trying to do too much or that the object under test is too complex.

Do you have any way to refactor your test or app code to avoid the "confusing edge case"? Perhaps by constructing a test double and expecting it to receive messages?

Comment: Maybe by telling my class that any new object should be a specific one that I create in my test? Is this common practice?

Comment: That sounds plausible. I can't speak to the popularity, but give it a shot!

Comment: This doesn't always mean code smell. Some probably have changed from `MyClass.my_method` to `MyClass.new.my_method` to make it more OO and less code smell.

Answer (score 31):

If you need to live with the code smell, [this rspec-mocks Github issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/910#issuecomment-265902511) suggests a solution along these lines:

```
receive_count = 0
allow_any_instance_of(MyClass).to receive(:my_method) { receive_count += 1 }

# Code to test here.

expect(receive_count).to be > 0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I would need, but rspec (3.5) still complains about being received by different objects... The message 'my_method' was received by #<MyClass:47073928928700> but has already been received by #<MyClass:0x000055a0819b45e8> (RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError)

Comment: a few years late, but just in case anyone needs help here. you're probably still using `expect_any_instance_of` which will throw that error when a second call is made. you have to change it to `allow_any_instance_of` which has no expectations on number of calls made

Comment: TL;DR: use `allow_any…` instead of `expect_any…`